# Optimizing queries on a relational DB where entities are full json objects and with another table with entity-value design

Tags: mysql, database

In my database, entities are stored as full JSON formatted objects. There is another table for properties of entities. Each property of an entity is stored its own row. In a sense, the second table holds properties of JSON entity.

I'm aware that this is a terrible design violating normal forms and also it is an anti-pattern called Entity-Attribute-Value.

For a simple query, I must make a number of joins and it is terrible for performance.

I wonder if there is a way for optimizing queries by reducing number of joins?

Solutions out of question since there are lots of constraints:

- normalizing tables
- migrating to a nosql engine

By the way, the database engine is MySQL 5.6.21. If I update the mysql db to another version of mysql, can I create queries on JSON objects directly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7.8 [supports JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) as a datatype. Without more details, it's hard to see if that will help you - but it will almost certainly be faster than the EAV queries you currently have to do.